# How to check if a field exists in a MySQL database using Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have this code to execute the statement where the user ID equals what a user has previously put in:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE Email = %s;", (self.emailEntry().get()))
```

I want to check if what the user entered is in the database and do something via an if statement. How would I do that?

Answer (score -1):

First of all try to run general query such as Select * from TableName , In this way you will get complete table so that you can check whether your required field is exists or not